# Sticky Nav that shrinks

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, sharepoint

```
$(document).scroll(function(){
    if($(this).scroll)
    {   
        $('nav').css({"width":"80%"});
    }
});
```

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/kap5/pen/ICstL)

New to js/jquery.. Some experience with CSS.  I'd like to use as little css and jquery as possible to get this effect: [website](http://tympanus.net/Blueprints/AnimatedHeader/) Shrinking nav on scroll.

That site has a demo and some code, but I feel like this can be achieved with a lot less CSS and Jquery.  For starters, I'm able to get the nav to decrease to 80% width on scroll, but it doesn't center or go back to 100% when scrolling back up.

Ultimately, I'd like to use this effect on SharePoint 2013 global navigation.  As that demo code is, I cannot get it work with SharePoint, so I am trying to start out with simple html and work my way up from there.

Anybody have experience with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this even thought usually it's common to see websites with the height of the header change. Following your example then, you can do the same with the width:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
  if($(document).scrollTop() > 0)

    {   
        $('nav').css({"width":"80%"});
    }
  else{
         $('nav').css({"width":"100%"});

  }
});
```

Usually it's not recommended to edit css properties with jQuery. It's better to add a class with CSS properties with jQuery.

```
 $(window).scroll(function(){
      if($(document).scrollTop() > 0)

        {   
             $('nav').addClass('width80');
        }
      else{
             $('nav').removeClass('width80');

      }
    });
```

Remember to define the nav.width80 class:

```
nav{
        width:100%;
} 
nav.width80{
        width:80%;
}
```

**DEMO** http://codepen.io/alexincarnati/pen/JngrK

Comment: Both great answers.  This answer didn't take additional CSS.  Thank you!

Comment: Usually I tend to define UI visuals and also transformations in CSS and add and remove classes in js. Now browsers support it smoothly! :)

Comment: Because it's part of the functionality that the framework offers, but of course it's not as performing as just adding and removing a class.

Comment: You can do it, but doesn't mean necessarily that it's the best way to do it. :)

Comment: Is there a way to do this without using jQuery.. just JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on("scroll",function(){
    if($(document).scrollTop()>50){
        $("nav").addClass("nav_small");
    } else{
        $("nav").removeClass("nav_small");
    }
});

nav.nav_small{width: 80%}
nav{width:100%}
```

that works easy;)